# Help understanding paritions and OS installation

Tags: partition, memory, pop-os

I installed pop-os on a Lenovo thinkpad x270 with 8 GB RAM and 256 GB disk capacity. I am not sure on how to interpret the disk allocation and am wondering if I'm using the whole disk at all. Here are some details  -

1. The Output of `lsblk` is

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
zram0           252:0    0   7.5G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1         259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0  1022M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0 229.5G  0 part  
│ └─cryptdata   253:0    0 229.5G  0 crypt 
│   └─data-root 253:1    0 229.5G  0 lvm   /
└─nvme0n1p4     259:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap   253:2    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

2. The output of `sudo fdisk -l` is

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: THNSF5256GPUK TOSHIBA                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 14FC93CB-14DB-49BC-925D-DA06EB6BE1A0

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      4096   2097150   2093055  1022M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   2097152  10485758   8388607     4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3  10485760 491725486 481239727 229.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 491725488 500114094   8388607     4G Linux swap


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptdata: 229.46 GiB, 246377963008 bytes, 481206959 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/data-root: 229.45 GiB, 246373416960 bytes, 481198080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap: 4 GiB, 4294442496 bytes, 8387583 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/zram0: 7.52 GiB, 8070889472 bytes, 1970432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

3. The following images are from disk usage analyser - [image: home folder] [image: pop-os]

This laptop is from someone else and I don't know how this configaration distribution came to be. From what I can tell, I managed to install pop-os on a smaller partition and am not actually using the full disk space.
Ideally, I'd like use the full disk with pop-os (there is no other os installed). Am I reading this wrong? Some explanation of the above outputs would be helpful. How do I use the full disk? Do I need to modify the partitions? If yes, details would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: small modifications in phrasing based on comments.

Comment: You seem to use the term "memory" when referring to disk space. The amount of RAM (i.e. memory) that the system has will have very little to do with the way the disk is partitioned.

Comment: yes, sorry my bad. I'm not aware of the terminology. Disk space is what I'm talking about.

Comment: /proc/meminfo has nothing to do with disk space though. `df` or so might be what you are interested in.

Comment: okay, if you have any advice that will make the question clearer that will help

Comment: So the only partition not for pop-os is the 4G recovery partition of Windows (nvme0n1p2). All other space is available for linux. I wouldn't take the hassle of reinstalling to get the additional 4GB. Try `df -h` to get the usage.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Can you also briefly tell me why there are multiple partitions? specifically - what is the difference between data-root and crypt data? they seem to have the same size. Why is the 4G recovery partition there? do I need it?